# Google Maps - info window not working (no console log errors)

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm working on my first google maps project. I have got multiple markers to appear and also used a custom marker. However I cannot get the info window to work when clicking a marker! Can anyone help?

When clicking a marker, nothing happens - it doesn't even enter the function (I set a console log).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var map,
    geocoder,
    bounds,
    address,
    marker = [],
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -74);

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        draggable: true
    };


    //styles
    var styles = [{
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "on" },
        { "hue": "#FF0000" },
        { "weight": 2 },
        { "gamma": 1 },
        { "lightness": 20 },
        { "saturation": 50 }
        ]
    }];


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    map.setOptions({styles: styles});


    var buildings = [
            '76 Ninth Ave, New York, NY ‎',
            '825 8th Ave, New York, NY ',
            '127 E 23rd St, New York, NY ‎'
];



    var contentString = '<div id="content">test</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString      
        });

    var marker = {url:'<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/theme/img/pointer2.png', scaledSize:new google.maps.Size(45, 72)};


    for (var i = 0; i < buildings.length; ++i) {
        (function(address) {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                     marker += new google.maps.Marker ({
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            icon: marker

                    });
                };
            });
        })(buildings[i]);
    };

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        console.log("test3");
        infowindow.open(map,marker);

        map.setZoom(8);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });

};


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be **V**ar buildings...?

Comment: Yes, good catch. Updated above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think first of all you have to move the click eventListener inside the loop. You have a marker array at the top, but you are overwriting it with `var marker = {url:'<?php echo site_url(); ?>...` , so let's rather call it "yourIcon" for the time being. Moreover, within the loop your adding all markers up to one single string, which makes no sense as far as I am concerned ;)
Within the loop, you then have to attach an eventListener to every single marker.

```
for (var i=0; i < buildings.length; i++) {
    // Create a new lexical scope by "copying the buildings"
    (function(address) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                // Create the marker
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });

                // Create the info window
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: address
                });

                // Add the eventListener
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                    map.setZoom(12);
                    map.panTo(this.getPosition());
                });                   
            };
        });
    })(buildings[i]);
}
```

You can see the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mwfire/vJDjJ/)

*P.S.*
You already avoided the closure issue in your question, I was just to tired to see it;)
Here is an approach to explain closures: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

**Edit 1: Wordpress**
In order to make this work in wordpress, you don't have to do much. I would suggest to use objects inside your buildings array, this way you can easily access more data.

This is how your buildings array could look like:

```
var buildings = [
    { address: '76 Ninth Ave, New York, NY‎', title: "Test 1" },
    { address: '825 8th Ave, New York, NY‎', title: "Test 2" },
    { address: '127 E 23rd St, New York, NY‎', title: "Test 3" }
];
```

The loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $postCount = 0; ?>
    var buildings = [
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $postcount++; ?>
        { address: '<?php customMetaAddressHere; ?>', title: '<?php the_title(); ?>', link: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>', }
        <?php if($postCount < sizeof($posts)) { ?>
        ,
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    ];
<?php else : ?>
    var buildings = [];
<?php endif; ?>
```

Change your Google marker loop to:

```
(function(building) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': building.address }, function(results, status) {
        // You have access to buildings.title as well
        ...
    });
})(buildings[i]);
```

This is untested, but you can see a fiddle of what I mean [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mwfire/vJDjJ/1/).

**Edit 2: Only one active infowindow**
If you want only one infowindow open at a time, it is best to create it outside the loop and only change it's content and position on marker click:

```
// Create the info window
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

for (var i=0; i < buildings.length; i++) {
    // Create a new lexical scope by "copying the buildings"
    (function(building) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': building.address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                // Create the marker
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });

                // Add the eventListener
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent("<b>" + building.title + "</b><br> " + building.address);
                    infowindow.setPosition(this.getPosition());
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                    map.setZoom(12);
                    map.panTo(this.getPosition());
                });               
            };
        });
    })(buildings[i]);
}
```

You can find a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mwfire/vJDjJ/2/).

Comment: thanks so much for your help - the info windows now work! THe only issue now is that when clicking a marker, the map zooms into one point. If you click another marker, it centers back to the same point. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, by the same point, I meant no matter what marker you click, it loads one specific.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that is the age old closure problem... Google maps has got an example on that https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure?hl=de I will update in a minute

Comment: I figured out how to make each marker load its proper location (http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/).. In your event listener for each marker, you have to change "marker[i]" to "this".  `infowindow.open(map, this);
                map.setZoom(8);
                map.setCenter(this.getPosition());`

Comment: Now to figure out how to get each marker to have its own corresponding content.

Comment: Thanks for readjusting all of the code!! I have one last question. What if I make things more complicated like making the content of each post the post title (see above, i replaced address with a, <h1> with php).

Comment: I would suggest to put all the Info of the locations inside an array as nested objects. I will add an example to the fiddle tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, thanks @mwfire, you're a lifesaver! I will attempt to solve it too (but may not succeed lol)

Comment: I think you were on to something when you mentioned closures. I have reworked it a bit, I will post code soon hopefully. But I am having an issue where I created a more indepth array ['123 address', 'title of building', 'building url'] and while the markers are set on the map with each location, the information that appears in each info window is the last element of the array!

Comment: thanks so much for all your help! Thanks for creating the new fiddle too, it helped avoid me in asking another question!

Comment: last question I promise! I tried to make it so that when I click a marker then click a different marker, the infowindow closes - no luck. I added infowindow.close(); in the addListner, but it didnt work. Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: I've implemented this code, and after adding 30 'buildings', the code is only adding 12 markers to the map. This may be a scope problem - still a bit of a complex concept for me. I added console logs to various parts in the loop - the console log before the (function(building) prints all 30 projects. A console log within if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) only prints 12! Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, so maybe the other points don't return an OK status. Try adding an `else` to the GeocoderStatus `if` and log the output there.

Comment: Great idea! I did that, this is the error I'm getting: Geocode was not successful for the following reason: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. I'm guessing I need to purchase a google maps api pro version haha